# ASP.NET Webforms Membership sample application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

Is there a quickstart application sample that demonstrates using the Login controls, roles, profile and uses best practices?

Comment: user, put a 200 bounty on it and I will write one just for you. no joke.

Answer (score 1):

Find following links useful

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/security/AspNetMembership.aspx

http://aspalliance.com/1658_Using_Forms_Authentication_with_Membership_Providers_in_ASPNET_20.2

This is one of the best link I found for membership authentication

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx

Hope this will help!

Comment: Jinal - I am looking for a quickstart coding sample demonstrating the use of the membership API and none of hte links mentioned have any code samples.

Answer (score 1):

The  ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool uses the Membership API. I think all of the source code is in there, you'll just have to import it into a project by yourself.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles

Comment: Does the WS Admin tool demonstrate the use of roles, login controls and profile? (I have used it to add members). Also, can you explain what you mean when you say "import it into a project"?

Comment: @user there are no profile management features and is in no way an example of best practices. It also relies heavily on impersonation making it's usefulness as an example of production use of the Membership and Roles providers questionable. In any case I have already created an updated vs08 web app project and fixed some bugs that MS has left in for the last 7 years. You can find it here: http://spikes.codeplex.com/releases/view/40655 Be sure to check the readme on how to start it up.

Comment: @code poet: I see we meet again. If you post your answer in an answer, I'll delete this.

Comment: How bout I just give you an upvote and leave it as is. You can add the URL and recap to your answer. While the OP may get some value from studying the app, it really does not meet the criteria stated in the question. But the reference you provide does have merit - I just provide some code. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am sure following link will be useful..

It is step by step guide

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: I do have a number of links with tutorials and articles. What I am looking for is a code sample. Please do not post multiple answers. Instead, edit your earlier answer.